# Set value for multiple vars in ng-click

Tags: angularjs, variables, set, directive

Is there a clever way to set the value for multiple variables inside an ng-click statement of a view without doing it through a controller function? For example, something along the lines of

```
<li ng-click="showLeftDiv = true, showRightDiv = false, showBottomDiv = false">
```

I need to show one div at a time, and hide all others (3+ divs).

Comment: As in JavaScript… `showLeftDiv = true; showRightDiv = false; showBottomDiv = false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct answer to your question is same as in controller:

```
<li ng-click="showLeftDiv = true; showRightDiv = false; showBottomDiv = false;"></li>
```

But I would do it different. You can use [ng-switch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch), [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf), [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) or [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide).

An example with ng-if:

```
<div id="leftDiv" ng-if="showDiv=='left'"></div>
<div id="rightDiv" ng-if="showDiv=='right'"></div>
<div id="bottomDiv" ng-if="showDiv=='bottom'"></div>
```

Then in your ng-click:

```
<li ng-click="showDiv='left'"></li>
```